# Counting the number of times a letter occurs at a certain position using python

Tags: python, string, count, position, frequency

I'm a python beginner and I've come across this problem and I'm not sure how I'd go about tackling it.

If I have the following sequence/strings:

GATCCG

GTACGC

How to I count the frequency each letter occurs at each position. ie) G occurs at position one twice in the two sequences, A occurs at position 1 zero times etc.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What format do you want it in?  Could you give us an example such as `{'g': [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], ...}`?  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, a dictionary would be good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)  and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) like so:

```
from  collections import defaultdict

sequences = ['GATCCG', 'GTACGC']
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))  # d[char][position] = count
for seq in sequences:
    for i, char in enumerate(seq):  # enum('abc'): [(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')]
        d[char][i] += 1

d['C'][3]  # 2
d['C'][4]  # 1
d['C'][5]  # 1
```

This builds a nested `defaultdict` that takes the character as first and the position as second key and provides the count of occurrences of said character in said position.

If you want lists of position-counts:

```
max_len = max(map(len, sequences))
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0]*max_len)  # d[char] = [pos0, pos12, ...]
for seq in sequences:
    for i, char in enumerate(seq): 
        d[char][i] += 1

d['G']  # [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what this is doing?

Comment: Oh thank you, I got some output and I understand it. I'd prefer the output to look a little more like {'g': [2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], ...}, is that possible at all?

Comment: So. Now you should be covered. I think the functionality of the defaultdicts is rather intuitive.

Comment: Sorry again, I'm getting a Type Error for the d[char].append[i] line.
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable?

Comment: I have made some edits. Use the current version. It is tested ;)

Comment: Never used defaultdics before, still getting familiar with it all!

Comment: This is so much help, thank you so much! thanks for explaining it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way but you can use zip to do a sort of transpose on the the strings, producing tuples of the letters in each position, e.g.:

```
x = 'GATCCG' 
y = 'GTACGC'

zipped = zip(x,y)

print zipped
```

will produce as output:

```
[('G', 'G'), ('A', 'T'), ('T', 'A'), ('C', 'C'), ('C', 'G'), ('G', 'C')]
```

You can see from the tuples that the first positions of the two strings contain two Gs, the second positions contain an A and a T, etc. Then you could use Counter (or some other method) to get at what you want.